# Тёмная тема в Android Studio меня тональность цвета

Tags: android, android-themes

у меня есть два файла themes и themes-night, также есть colors и colors-night. В colors устанавливаю цвет с именем background1 и в colors-night переопределяю его с другим цветом. Есть атрибут background1 в themes и themes-night даю ему цвет @colors/background1. При запуске приложения в светлой теме отображается правильный цвет, а в тёмной теме отображается цвет для тёмной темы из colors-night, но с изменённым тоном цвета. Должен быть такой [image: введите сюда описание изображения], но отображается такой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите, пожалуйста, понять почему так

Comment: [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1318761/edit) вопрос, укажите в вопросе, какие значения цветов вы задаете.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему самостоятельно - всё вышло очень смешно, хоть больше хочется плакать. Для отладки я использую физической устройство Xiaomi, в настройках я нашел параметры тёмной темы этой оболочки и убрал функцию затемнения, которая как раз и изменяла цвет.